# Ploting graph of vectors using c++,linux

Tags: c++, linux, vector, graph, eigen

I've two vectors of type double, and i want to draw their graph in the xy coordinate/axis: Now, can i have any recommendations or suggestions to do this task using c++ in Linux OS? I'm using Eigen Library to generate my vectors and to operate on matrices, any idea if Eigen have the functionality to draw graphs of vectors in real time? thanks.

my vectors are like:

```
Xaxis_vector=(2,3,2,4,6,7,8,1,3) 
Yaxis_vector=(12,13,22,4,26,7,8,21,43)
```

or a sample code as follows:

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  VectorXd Xaxis_vector(10); 
  VectorXd Yaxis_vector(10); 
  for(int i=0;i<10,i++)
  {
    Xaxis_vector[i]=i+1;
    Yaxis_vector[i]=2*i-4;
  }
  //In here i want to do graph plotting task...any help.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (by piping to it) [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or perhaps [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

If you want only to show something on the screen, consider [Qt](http://qt.io/), or [libSDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) etc...

Comment: Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch . your suggestion helped me well, the "gnuplot">>http://www.gnuplot.info/. But one more thing, the generated graph is not smooth. any idea to make it smooth?

Comment: Ask a new question, showing the generated gnuplot code and a corresponding graph image. But read the documentation of `gnuplot` before asking.